# Creating string array from csv file

Tags: input, strings, csv

I would like to create some name badges using a loop. I have a spreadsheet with names and affiliations that I save in names.csv file as follows

```
"Name1","Surname1","Affiliation1",
"Name2","Surname2","Affiliation2",
"Name3","Surname3","Affiliation3"
```

I can copy the content of names.csv in a string array and use a loop to recover the entries. The following is an example of working code producing the output Surname2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{array}

\def\names{{"Name1","Surname1","Affiliation1",
"Name2","Surname2","Affiliation2",
"Name3","Surname3","Affiliation3"}}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{\names[4]}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

I can use this idea to create hundreds of name badges in a loop. But instead of writing the whole list in the .tex file I would like to call directly my names.csv file. I used the modified code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{array}

\def\names{{\input{names.csv}}}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{\names[4]}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

which apparently enters in an endless loop. I understood that `\input{}` works just as copy-pastying, but it doesn't seem the case. Of course I can work in the spreadsheet and then copy paste the names.csv file content, but I would like to understand what happens. Any clues?

PS edit: The suggested solution is enough for my case. But still I would like to be able to define macros with `\input'. It seems that`\input{}' inside a macro is not expanded immediately. I mean if I have some code in `file.tex', that I want to plugin in a new macro,`\def\mymacro{\input{file}}' will save `\mymacro' as '\input{file}' and will only look what's inside the file when I call the macro in the document. That's why in the previous example`\names' is not understood as an array. In the same way

```
\begin{filecontent*}{newfile.tex}
\input{file}
\end{filecontent*}
```

will save the code `\input{file}' in`newfile.tex', but not the content in `file.tex'. Anyone has any idea how to force input to expand?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of importing the whole csv file you can read it row wise. There are some packages for this, here I use `csvsimple`. The file `names.csv` is created by the `filecontents` environment just to have it all in one file for this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%% Create file
\begin{filecontents*}{names.csv}
Name1, Surname1, Affiliation1
Name2, S. Urname2, A f filiation2
Name3, Surname3, Affiliation3
Name4, Surname4, Affiliation4
Name5, Surname5, Affiliation5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
List of participants:
\begin{itemize}
  \csvreader[no head]{names.csv}{1=\name, 2=\surname, 3=\affiliation}{%
  \item \name\ \surname\ at \affiliation
  }
\end{itemize}

Badges:\newline
\csvreader[no head]{names.csv}{1=\name, 2=\surname, 3=\affiliation}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
    \node at (3,2){\Large\name\ \surname};
    \node at (3,1.3){\affiliation};
    %% Logo
    \fill[color=red!40] (0.7,3.3) circle(1);
    \node[fill=green!40,opacity=0.5,rounded corners=5pt,anchor=west] at (0.8,3.5){\textsf{The Epic Event}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (0.8,3.5){\textsf{The Epic Event}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is nice enough for my case, and runs smoothly. But still I wonder if it is possible to work with arrays, for a more flexible case.

Answer (score 1):

The `readarray` package is set up to digest file data into arrays.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{names.csv}
Name1,Surname1,Affiliation1,
Name2,Surname2,Affiliation2,
Name3,Surname3,Affiliation3
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\begin{document}

\readdef{names.csv}\namedata

\readarray\namedata\names[-,\ncols]

\names[2,2] and \names[3,3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use readarray to reproduce the functionality of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634894/2288?

Comment: @Diaa Given that each row of the file could contain a different number of comma-separated entries, I'm thinking that `listofitems` might have a better chance of working...however, you might use `readarray`'s `\readdef` to get the file contents into a `\def`, to then be operated on by `\readlist*` of the `listofitems` package.

Comment: @Diaa For example, using the `mycoeffs.csv` file data in your cited question, `\ignoreemptyitems
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{mycoeffs.csv}\mydata
\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*\mylist{\mydata}` will get the file into an array `\mylist`, such that `\mylist[2,1]` will yield the first element of the second row, that is `Second`; `\mylist[3,2]` will similarly yield `5` (the 2nd element of the 3rd row); and the number of row elements can be determined with, for example, `\listlen\mylist[3]`, which indicates that row 3 has `4` elements in it.

Comment: @Diaa Once the data is into an array, as shown above, then you just need a macro to identify from which row you want to extract data, and to set the polynomial, based on how many elements are in the given row data.

Comment: Thanks for your input; the main challenge is that I need to look up the row and access its values by searching for the rows using the cell in the first column. So, I can find the data I need without having to remember where it lies as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575030/storing-a-csv-row-columns-in-a-list-array-and-indexing-into-it?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576462/a-row-of-csv-data-is-not-saved-after-checking-for-its-emptiness-and-existence?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `\names` so that its definition is the contents of the file. This means some expansion is required:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{array}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\endlinechar=-1\relax
\everyeof{\noexpand}\relax
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\names{{\@@input names.csv }}}\x

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{\names[4]}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why and how this works to load the contents of a file into a macro? I tried forever with `\edef` and `\expandafter` to get just the actual text in a file expanded into a macro, and I kept getting weird complaints like `Argument of \@iinput has an extra }` that I can't parse. What is `\@@input`, as opposed to normal `\input`? Why are you creating a group and then ending it inside `\x`? Why do you need to define `\x` at all if you then immediately use it? Where is the documentation for `\everyeof` and how do you know to use it here?