# How to correctly parse a CSV file row-by-row with different number of commas/columns from each row to another?

Tags: expl3, xparse, csv

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634894/2288), with this csv file

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
    TeMaxPartLoad,163.0576,,,,
    MaxSpeedTR,1065.9,,,,,
    coeffs, 3, 5, 9 , 8, 6 ,
\end{filecontents*}
```

I get the expected output

[image]

however, changing the number of commas in the first row makes the output wrong

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
    TeMaxPartLoad,163.0576,
    MaxSpeedTR,1065.9,,,,,
    coeffs, 3, 5, 9 , 8, 6 ,
\end{filecontents*}
```

[image]

So, how to fix this unwanted behavior?

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mydata.csv}
    TeMaxPartLoad,163.0576,
    MaxSpeedTR,1065.9,,,,,
    coeffs, 3, 5, 9 , 8, 6 ,
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Reading the file (based on <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575055/73317>)
\ior_new:N \l__diaa_csv_ior
\bool_new:N \l__diaa_csv_str_bool
\seq_new:N \l__diaa_csv_tmp_seq

% str mode (bool/star), key column, label, value columns, file
\NewDocumentCommand \ReadCSV { s O{1} m O{} m }
{
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
    { \bool_set_true:N \l__diaa_csv_str_bool }
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__diaa_csv_str_bool }
    \diaa_csv_read:nnnn {#3} {#2} {#4} {#5}
}

% label, key column, value columns, file
\cs_new_protected:Npn \diaa_csv_read:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
{
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#3}       % Detect number of columns and use 2 to last
    {
        \ior_open:NnTF \l__diaa_csv_ior {#4}
        {
            \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_csv_str_bool
            { \ior_str_get:NN }
            { \ior_get:NN }
            \l__diaa_csv_ior \l_tmpa_tl
            
            \ior_close:N \l__diaa_csv_ior
            \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { , } \l_tmpa_tl
            \seq_clear:N \l__diaa_csv_tmp_seq
            \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq }
            { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__diaa_csv_tmp_seq {##1} }
        }
        { \msg_error:nnn { diaa } { file-not-found } {#4} }
    }
    { \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__diaa_csv_tmp_seq { , } {#3} } % explicit columns
    
    \ior_open:NnTF \l__diaa_csv_ior {#4}
    {
        \prop_new:c { g__diaa_csv_#1_prop }
        \__diaa_csv_read:nn {#1} {#2}
        \ior_close:N \l__diaa_csv_ior
    }
    { \msg_error:nnn { diaa } { file-not-found } {#4} }
}

\msg_new:nnn { diaa } { file-not-found }
{ File~`#1'~not~found. }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_put:Nnn { cxV }

% label, key column
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__diaa_csv_read:nn #1 #2
{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_csv_str_bool
    { \ior_str_map_inline:Nn }
    { \ior_map_inline:Nn }
    \l__diaa_csv_ior
    {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } {##1} % split one CSV row
        \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__diaa_csv_tmp_seq
        {
            \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {####1} } }
        }
        
        \prop_put:cxV { g__diaa_csv_#1_prop }
        { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2} }
        \l_tmpa_tl
    }
}

\keys_define:nn { diaa / getPolyFromRow }
{
    global-assignment .bool_set:N = \l__diaa_gpfr_global_assignment_bool,
    global-assignment .default:n = true,
    global-assignment .initial:n = false,
    variable .tl_set:N = \l__diaa_gpfr_variable_name_tl,
    variable .value_required:n = true,
    variable .initial:n = X,
    typographical-variant .str_set:N = \l__diaa_gpfr_typographical_variant_str,
    typographical-variant .value_required:n = true,
    typographical-variant .initial:n = default,
}

% \getPolyFromRow will temporarily store the result in this variable. This
% allows us not to lose the result when the group started for \keys_set:nn
% ends (if the user chose to perform a local assignment, this must be done
% after closing that group).
\tl_new:N \g__diaa_gpfr_result_tl

% Options, macro for result, key, datafile label
\NewDocumentCommand \getPolyFromRow { O{} m m m }
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { diaa / getPolyFromRow } {#1}
    
    % Globally define _gfunc function aliases that perform global or local
    % assignments depending on \l__diaa_gpfr_global_assignment_bool. They
    % will be used *after* we close the current group.
    \bool_set_true:N \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool
    \__diaa_gpfr_define_tl_func_aliases:
    
    % Store the result in \g__diaa_gpfr_result_tl for now.
    \bool_set_true:N \l__diaa_gpfr_global_assignment_bool
    \diaa_get_poly_from_row:Nnn \g__diaa_gpfr_result_tl {#3} {#4}
    \group_end:
    
    % Use the globally-defined aliases to perform the user-chosen (local or
    % global) kind of assignment.
    \__diaa_clear_gfunc:N #2    % make sure the tl var #2 is defined
    \__diaa_set_eq_gfunc:NN #2 \g__diaa_gpfr_result_tl % set it
}

% True to globally define the aliases and give them _gfunc names rather than
% _func
\bool_new:N \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__diaa_gpfr_define_tl_func_aliases:
{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_gpfr_global_assignment_bool
    {
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { clear }     { N }  \tl_gclear_new:N
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { set_eq }    { NN } \tl_gset_eq:NN
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { put_right } { Nn } \tl_gput_right:Nn
    }
    {
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { clear }     { N }  \tl_clear_new:N
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { set_eq }    { NN } \tl_set_eq:NN
        \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN { put_right } { Nn } \tl_put_right:Nn
    }
}

% Locally or globally define an alias for a function. The alias is defined
% globally with a gfunc name if \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool is true.
%
% #1: stem such as “clear”, “put_right”, etc.
% #2: signature of the alias (e.g., “Nn”)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__diaa_gpfr_define_alias:nnN #1#2
{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool
    { \cs_gset_eq:cN }
    { \cs_set_eq:cN }
    {
        __diaa_#1_
        \bool_if:NT \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool { g }
        func:#2
    }
}

\int_new:N \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int
\tl_new:N \l__dia_gpfr_row_values_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__diaa_put_right_func:Nn { Nx }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__diaa_get_poly_from_row_append_monomial:Nnn { NnV }

% Macro for result, key, datafile label
\cs_new_protected:Npn \diaa_get_poly_from_row:Nnn #1#2#3
{
    % Locally define function aliases that perform global or local assignments
    % depending on \l__diaa_gpfr_global_assignment_bool: \__diaa_clear_func:Nn,
    % \__diaa_put_right_func:Nn, etc.
    \bool_set_false:N \l__diaa_gpfr_dtfa_global_aliases_bool
    \__diaa_gpfr_define_tl_func_aliases:
    
    % Retrieve the coefficients
    \prop_get:cnN { g__diaa_csv_#3_prop } {#2} \l__dia_gpfr_row_values_tl
    
    % Let's put (1 + degree) for now in this int variable.
    \int_zero:N \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__dia_gpfr_row_values_tl
    {
        \tl_if_empty:nT {##1} { \tl_map_break: }
        \int_incr:N \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int
    }
    
    \__diaa_clear_func:N #1        % initialize #1 as a tl var if necessary
    \bool_set_false:N \l_tmpa_bool % true: add + operator if next coeff is > 0
    
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__dia_gpfr_row_values_tl % loop over the coefficients
    {
        % Degree of the monomial we're about to output
        \int_decr:N \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int
        % Early termination condition if the row is not full of coefficients
        \int_compare:nNnT { \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int } < { 0 }
        { \tl_map_break: }
        
        \fp_compare:nNnF {##1} = { 0 }
        {
            % Insert a + operator if necessary
            \bool_if:NTF \l_tmpa_bool
            {
                \fp_compare:nNnT {##1} > { 0 }
                { \__diaa_put_right_func:Nn #1 { + } }
            }
            { \bool_set_true:N \l_tmpa_bool }
            
            % Insert the monomial
            \__diaa_get_poly_from_row_append_monomial:NnV #1 {##1}
            \l__diaa_gpfr_variable_name_tl
        }
    }
}

\msg_new:nnn { diaa } { gpfr-unknown-typo-variant }
{ Unknown~typographical~variant~for~\token_to_str:N \getPolyFromRow :~`#1'. }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \msg_error:nnn { nnV }

% Macro, coefficient, variable name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__diaa_get_poly_from_row_append_monomial:Nnn #1#2#3
{
    \str_case_e:nnF { \l__diaa_gpfr_typographical_variant_str }
    {
        { default }     { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 \times #3 ^ } }
        { with-braces } { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 \times {#3} ^ } }
    }
    {
        \msg_error:nnV { diaa } { gpfr-unknown-typo-variant }
        \l__diaa_gpfr_typographical_variant_str
    }
    
    \__diaa_put_right_func:Nx #1
    {
        \int_case:nnF { \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int } % depending on the degree...
        {
            { 0 } { \exp_not:n {#2} } % degree 0 → only the coefficient
            { 1 } { \exp_not:n { #2 \times #3 } }
        }
        { % Other degrees
            \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl % use the selected variant
            % Use braces in case the exponent has several digits
            { \int_use:N \l__diaa_gpfr_degree_int }
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\ReadCSV{DrivingData}{mydata.csv}

\getPolyFromRow{\eq}{coeffs}{DrivingData}

\begin{document}
    $\eq$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you are interested in expanding the current code, but as an alternative here a version with `xstring`. The idea is to read the file verbatim (using the `catchfile` package), then process the last line, split off the first coefficient, print it, and recursively continue with the rest of the line.

This requires that 1. the line with the coefficients is the final line in the csv file and 2. the coefficients line is labeled *coeffs* and 3. there is no space between the word *coeffs* and the first comma. All three requirements could be addressed with some more code but this serves as a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\printeq#1{%
% count comma's (=number of coefficients-1)
\StrCount{#1}{,}[\ncomma]%
% final coefficient, print as is
\ifnum\ncomma=0\relax#1\else%
   % else split current coefficient from the rest of the line
   \StrCut{#1}{,}{\coeff}{\newcoeffs}
   % 2nd last, don't print power
   \ifnum\ncomma=1\relax\coeff\times X+\else%
      % else print power
      \coeff\times X^{\ncomma}+%
   \fi%
   % recursive call if not final coefficient
   \printeq{\newcoeffs}%
\fi%
}

\begin{document}
% read csv file verbatim
\makeatletter
\CatchFileDef{\fulltext}{coeffdata.csv}{\let\do\@makeother\dospecials}
\makeatother
% find final line that starts with "coeffs,"
\StrBehind*{\fulltext}{coeffs,}[\coeffs]
% remove all spaces
\StrDel{\coeffs}{ }[\coeffs]
% remove final comma if present
\IfEndWith{\coeffs}{,}{\StrGobbleRight{\coeffs}{1}[\coeffs]}{}
% print equation recursively
$\printeq{\coeffs}$

\end{document}
```

The result is as in the first screenshot in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the expansion of the original code is a must since it is a part of a bigger one. Anyway, thanks again